# Bazel & automatically generated cpp / hpp files

Tags: c++, bazel

I am starting to use Bazel as my C++ project build system.

**However I am stuck with the following problem:**

I am in a scenario where I automatically generate the file.hpp file.cpp (literate programming).

To reproduce my problem one can simply use this minimal generator:

```
-- file.sh --
#!/bin/sh
echo "int foo();" >> file.hpp
echo "#include \"myLib/file.hpp\"\n\nint foo() { return 2017; }" >> file.cpp
```

My project repo is: (WORKSPACE is an empty file)

```
├── myLib
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── file.sh
└── WORKSPACE
```

The BUILD file is

```
genrule(
  name = "tangle_file",
  srcs = ["file.sh"],
  outs = ["file.cpp","file.hpp"],
  cmd =  "./$(location file.sh);cp file.cpp $(@D);cp file.hpp $(@D);"
)

cc_library(
    name = "file",
    srcs = ["file.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["file.hpp"],
#    deps = [":tangle_file"],
    visibility = ["//bin:__pkg__"],
)
```

I have two problems:

**Question (A), dealing with the genrule() part:**

The fact that I must use

```
cmd =  "./$(location file.sh);cp file.cpp $(@D);cp file.hpp $(@D);"
```

is quite mysterious.

My first attempt was:

```
cmd =  "./$(location file.sh)"
```

However in that case I get the following error:

> declared output 'myLib/file.cpp' was not created by genrule. This is probably because the genrule actually didn't create this output, or because the output was a directory and the genrule was run remotely (note that only the contents of declared file outputs are copied from genrules run remotely)

**Question (B), dealing with the cc_library() part**

I do not know how to make Bazel aware of that the **:file** target depends on the **:tangle_file** target.

If I uncomment:

```
deps = [":tangle_file"],
```

I get the following error:

> in deps attribute of cc_library rule //myLib:file: genrule rule '//myLib:tangle_file' is misplaced here (expected cc_inc_library, cc_library, objc_library, experimental_objc_library or cc_proto_library).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Question (A)

The error that you are seeing is because the genrule cmd is not run inside of its output directory. If you hardcoded `bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/myLib/file.cpp` instead of `file.cpp` in your `file.sh` script, it would work. However, the recommended approach would be for your script to takes its output directory as an argument.

For example,

```
genrule(
  name = "tangle_file",
  srcs = ["file.sh"],
  outs = ["file.cpp","file.hpp"],
  cmd =  "./$(location file.sh) $(@D)"
)
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "int foo();" >> $1/file.hpp
echo "#include \"myLib/file.hpp\"\n\nint foo() { return 2017; }" >> $1/file.cpp
```

## Question (B)

The fact that you have

```
srcs = ["file.cpp"],
hdrs = ["file.hpp"],
```

in your `cc_library` is what tells Bazel that it depends on the `genrule`, since the `genrule` creates those files. If you want to make it more explicit, you could use the label syntax, which does the same thing:

```
srcs = ["//myLib:file.cpp"],
hdrs = ["//myLib:file.hpp"],
```

Comment: Thank you! I patched my files according to your explanations and everything worked like a charm!