# Dispatching C++ generated files into srcs and hdrs

Tags: bazel

In the Bazel official documentation there is an [example](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/functions.html#glob_example) explaining how to create a Java library built from regular java files and files generated by a :gen_java_srcs rule. I rewrite this code here for ease of reading:

```
java_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]) + [":gen_java_srcs"],
    deps = "...",
)

genrule(
    name = "gen_java_srcs",
    outs = [
        "Foo.java",
        "Bar.java",
    ],
    ...
)
```

Now in a C++ perspective, I am in a scenario where the genrule generates two kind of files: .hpp and .cpp:

```
genrule(
    name = "gen_cpp_srcs",
    outs = [
        "myFile_1.hpp","myFile_2.hpp",...,"myFile_N.hpp",
        "myFile.cpp","myFile_2.cpp",...,"myFile_N.cpp",
    ],
    ...
)
```

where N is some tens.

**My problem/question is: how to write the cc_library rule, with an automatic dispatching of the hpp and cpp files into hdrs and srcs field?**

I want something like:

```
cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = glob(["*.cpp"]) + (howto: .cpp files of [":gen_cpp_srcs"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.hpp"]) + (howto: .hpp files of [":gen_cpp_srcs"]),
    ...
)
```

Some magic like:

```
output_filter(":gen_cpp_srcs","*.cpp")
```

would be perfect, but I do not know enough of Bazel to make it real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Globs only get expanded when they're passed into rules, so you'll need to write a simple [rule](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/rules.html). I would package it like this (in a file named `filter.bzl`):

```
# The actual rule which does the filtering.
def _do_filter_impl(ctx):
  return struct(
    files = set([f for f in ctx.files.srcs if f.path.endswith(ctx.attr.suffix)]),
  )
_do_filter = rule(
  implementation = _do_filter_impl,
  attrs = {
    "srcs": attr.label_list(
      mandatory = True,
      allow_files = True,
    ),
    "suffix": attr.string(
      mandatory = True,
    ),
  },
)

# A convenient macro to wrap the custom rule and cc_library.
def filtered_cc_library(name, srcs, hdrs, **kwargs):
  _do_filter(
    name = "%s_hdrs" % name,
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    srcs = hdrs,
    suffix = ".hpp",
  )
  _do_filter(
    name = "%s_srcs" % name,
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    srcs = srcs,
    suffix = ".cpp",
  )
  native.cc_library(
    name = name,
    srcs = [ ":%s_srcs" % name ],
    hdrs = [ ":%s_hdrs" % name ],
    **kwargs
  )
```

This is what my demo `BUILD` file looks like (I changed the globs so they both include *.cpp and *.hpp files; using the label of a genrule will work the same way):

```
load("//:filter.bzl", "filtered_cc_library")

filtered_cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = glob(["*.*pp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.*pp"]),
)
```

This is easy to extend to more sophisticated filtering by changing `_do_filter_impl`. In particular, changing `suffix` to an [attr.string_list](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/attr.html#string_list) so you can accept multiple C/C++ source/header extensions seems like a good idea.

Comment: Many thanks, your code is really valuable for me to learn how to extends Bazel for my stuff (I think that the official doc lacks a little bit of examples/explanations concerning the Skylark language).

Comment: Reading your code and Bazel doc, I just saw that [according to the Bazel doc](https://bazel.build/designs/skylark/declared-providers.html#migration-path-and-support-for-legacy-providers) `return struct(...)` is deprecated. I modified your code with `return [DefaultInfo(files = ..)]`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the genrule by name (`:gen_cpp_srcs`) will give you *all of the outputs* of the genrule, as you have noted. Instead, you can depend on the individual outputs of the genrule (e.g. `hdrs = [:myFile.hpp]` and `srcs = [:myFile.cpp]`).

See also the answer to [Bazel & automatically generated cpp / hpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312549/bazel-automatically-generated-cpp-hpp-files).

Comment: Reading your answer I just realized that my problem was not clearly explained. I re-edited my question to make it more understandable. In summary, I am wondering how to filter one rule output into another rule input, selecting only some types of file

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you know the total number of files that should be generated. Can you put those in their own variables and then reuse them in both targets. Something like this in your BUILD file:

```
output_cpp_files = [
   "myFile_1.cpp",
   "myFile_2.cpp",
   "myFile_3.cpp"
]

output_hpp_files = [
   "myFile_1.hpp",
   "myFile_2.hpp",
   "myFile_3.hpp"
]

genrule(
    name = "gen_cpp_srcs",
    outs = output_cpp_files + output_hpp_files,
    cmd = """
        touch $(OUTS)
    """
)

cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = output_cpp_files,
    hdrs = output_hpp_files
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have not the information about the size, that is the reason why I wanted to do it programmatically. Anyway, thank you: I like your genrule() which is a good trick to generate fake outputs.