# bazel share files between different test targets

Tags: bazel

I know that bazel runs all commands in isolated sandboxes, however, I want to break them deliberately.
Suppose I've got a project with the following layout:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── cpp
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── foo.cpp
│   └── test_foo.cpp
├── python
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── test_foo.py
└── WORKSPACE
```

The file `python/BUILD` contains a `py_test` rule that runs some python tests that leave some artifacts (let's say some binary files).
The file `cpp/BUILD` contains a `cc_test` rule that runs some cpp tests that require the artifacts left by the python tests.

The question is how I can do this? It would be better if the possible solution would provide all advantages of the incremental build system e.g. not running the python tests if they are older than artifacts and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way for generating code for testing is a [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule), see example for [the python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828671/4638604). After you have your `genrule` target (let say `//path/to:foo_gen`) all you have to do is to add the label to the `cc_test` `data` attribute:

```py
cc_test(
  data = ['/path/to:foo_gen'],
...
)
```

File specified in the `outs` attibute of the `genrule` (see example above) will be available at path `./path/to/file_specified_in_outs`

Comment: I'm afraid that `genrule` is not suitable here because it works with sh commands, nor with bazel rules and it requires specifying the output files that is a bit inconvenient in my case. On the other hand `data`  field of the `cc_test` would be useful on the second step, after artifacts have already been generated

Comment: With bash you can run any bazel target. In my previous project I was using a python  target (`py_binary`) to generate a XML file for `cc_test`, and it was working. Just use magical `$(location //src:foo_tool)`. About specifying files: it is how bazel works: inputs and outputs must be know to perform dependency tracking. To avoid it just create one `sh_test` target, which will generate files and then run your second test inside that shell script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my case helps you.

I was able to extract **py_test** artifacts with the following **genrule**:

```
genrule(
    name = "target_name",
    outs = [
        "target_output.tar",
    ],
    cmd = "./$(location //dependent_target) ; \
echo Writing generated file: ; find ./bazel-out/ -name 'my_archive.tar' ; echo To this output: ; \
echo $@ ; find ./bazel-out/ -name 'target_output.tar' -exec cat {} > $@ \\;",
    tools = [
        "//dependent_target",
    ],
)
```

After a while I have found simple and correct way: just use TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR bazel variable, see https://bazel.build/reference/test-encyclopedia